# Evaluation of $\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\ln x}\bigg)dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluation of $$\int^{1}_{0}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\ln x}\bigg)dx$$

Let $$I = \int^{1}_{0}\bigg(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{1}{\ln x}\bigg)dx = \int^{1}_{0}\frac{(1-x)+\ln x}{(1-x)\ln x}dx$$

Now How can i solve after that , Help required, Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason to expect a reasonably nice closed form?

Comment: To Daniel Fischer i don,t have any idea,it may be.

Comment: See the definition of Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually know that this integral is equal to the [Euler Mascheroni constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant).

$$\gamma=\int _0^1\left ({1\over1-x}+{1\over\ln x}\right)dx\approx0.57721566490153286060651209008240243104215933593992$$